# iOS - Posting to Facebook... is the icon this one?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, twitter

I am posting to Facebook using the social api of iOS 6.

I am using the tradicional SLComposeViewController, like in..

```
 SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

...

at some point I do

```
[controller addImage:imageFacebook];
```

where imageFacebook is a screenshot that is 280 pixels high and then I post to Facebook.

My problem is this. I am following similar approach with the twitter API, but when that little window shows, there is a thumbnail of the image I am sending, hold by a clips on the right side, but on the facebook counterpart I see this safari-like icon. Is this normal? I would be a happy man if I was seen here a miniature of the image being posted, as I saw with the twitter API...

NOTE: the image is being posted correctly to Facebook... my problem is this icon on the posting window.

Is there a way to change that icon?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you changed your icon in app settings inside your registered app in FaceBook?

Comment: can you translate that? what do you mean?

Comment: Your registered app on facebook. Add an icon there.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know this is not necessary anymore with iOS 6

Comment: SLComposeViewController is detached from your Facebook app (it works independently, posting from "iOS"). See Venkat's answer below--add an image to the SLComposeViewController instance.

Comment: Do you get the same thing when you use the Facebook SDK for iOS6?

Comment: I have not tried that. Too complex to what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler = myBlock;
    [controller setInitialText:@"Enter Your Text Here:"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image001-794043.jpeg"]];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}
```

Comment: @RubberDuck:AddImage is your ICON

Comment: addImage is what I am using, as stated in my question, but the icon it shows is this safari-like icon, not the image I am adding. My controller is created exactly as you post here. Can you please try on your side and see if you see the icon?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure myself but the safari-like icon would mean you added a URL (addURL:). The order of the image and url thumbnails is probably the order in which you add them. Still, I've never been able to show image thumbnail in facebook postings. I wonder how you pulled that off. See my other question+answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988183/show-attached-image-on-top-of-slcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Edit: As the Safari icon means "URL", I was able to show a thumbnail of the attached image by removing addURL: alltogether. It's weird. If you don't add a URL, you have the thumbnail of the image. You can even change the album @ Facebook in which the image will be posted. If you add a URL, you ONLY get that Safari icon. Weird.