# Show attached image on top of SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios

When adding an image to SLComposeViewController, the image is shown to the right in the SLComposeViewController view. However it's shown below (as in layer below) another default image looking like a compass. On top of that is a clip. What is this compass image? I'd like to show the attached image on top. Would be nice instead of that grey thing.

[image]

The attached image is the white image below the compass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it.

The compass means you also attached a URL to the social posting.

The order of the image and the compass is determined by the way you add that stuff to the SLComposeViewController itself. I was adding the URL first, then the image. Just change the order, and the things clipped to the posting will also change order. The first added item will show on top as it seems.

This is also true for TWTweetComposeViewController in iOS 5.

It seems the above works for Twitter. Facebook never shows any attached image...?

Edit: As for Facebook - As the Safari icon means "URL", I was able to show a thumbnail of the attached image by removing addURL: alltogether. It's weird. If you don't add a URL, you have the thumbnail of the image. You can even change the album @ Facebook in which the image will be posted. If you add a URL, you ONLY get that Safari icon. Weird.